# Swift 4.0 Right Padding a String

Tags: swift, string, generics, padding

I padded a Swift String up to X amount of characters.  Which is the most efficient way to achieve this in Swift 4.0?

**Option 1**

```
extension String {
    mutating func right_padding(padding: Int, padding_char: Character) {
        let idx = self.endIndex
        for _ in (1...padding) {
            self.insert(padding_char, at: idx)
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**
SO article: [Padding a swift String for printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338137/padding-a-swift-string-for-printing)

```
let test = "ghost" + "\(String(repeatElement("!", count: 40)))"
```

**Option 3**

`???`

Option 2 seems the simplest & most efficient, but I may be missing a better way...

Comment: Note - there needs to be code to handle null strings and overly long strings but I purposely removed it.

Comment: Can you explain why the answers given in the question you linked aren't satisfactory for you.

Comment: I already linked that article in the original post.   There are so many APIs available in Swift 4. https://oleb.net/blog/2017/11/swift-4-strings/  I wonder if there is now a better way of achieving the same padding?

Comment: I know. What's wrong with the answers that it gives? Why would they not be the answer to your question? In particular https://stackoverflow.com/a/39215372/169346