# How can I read characters of a String with String format in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying use String(format:, ) for reading some characters from left or right, do we have something for this job?

for example reading 2 characters from left would be: "AB" like this: "%2L@"

my code:

```
let stringOfText = String(format: "%@", "ABCDEF")
```

Comment: `"ABCDEF".prefix(2)`. `String(format` is not needed.

Comment: thanks, I know that I was think since we could do "%.5f" or "%05d" maybe I could do some sort of things on String as well

Comment: No, you can't, the *decimal places modifiers* affect only numeric values.

Comment: @willy https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447981/2303865

Comment: @ vadian: I know that as well, I do not wanted use decimal places modifiers for String, It was an example to show my idea, I wanted to know if we got any does modifiers for String as well, like this: "%2L@" "%2R@"

Comment: @LeoDabus: that was helpful, voted!

Comment: @willy updated the post

Comment: @LeoDabus: that is nice thanks

Comment: @willy regarding your last question if you implement only `SignedNumeric` method, use a negative value and explicitly set the resulting type to be Uint `let add: UInt = addition(a: -3, b: -2)` Xcode will throw an error saying that `addition(a:b:)' requires that 'UInt' conform to 'SignedNumeric'` but it you implement only the Numeric version and try to do the same you get a # error  `Negative integer '-3' overflows when stored into unsigned type 'UInt'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String(format:) is usually to transform a different value type into a string.

Since you already have a string, you don't really need this method.

try:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894830-prefix